# Splitting a list of elements summing up to a cutoff value

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Recently I got into a very (basic) problem. My feeling is that it must have a very theoretical solution which I am not aware of. The problem statement is this:

Let [x_1, x_2, ..., x_n] is a list of positive integers. I need to make the minimum split of these numbers such that sum of those numbers in each split should not exceed N.

For example: The list is [67, 56, 12345, 555555, 555555, 555555] and N=1000000, then the one minimum splits would be [[555555, 12345, 67, 56], [555555], [555555]].

One solution I thought is like this:

1. sort the list.
2. Take max value and add minimum values one by one so that the some do not exceed N.
3. Remove elements used in 2 from the list and try 2 and 3 again on the modified list until the list exhaust.

The problem is that I am not sure it will provide the minimum split.

Thanks for any solution.

Comment: This looks like the bin packing problem, which has multiple solutions online.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur thanks a lot, that's what wanted to know.